# Question about implicit method in Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: implicit, pde

I am working on incompressible Navier-Stokes equations in 2D and trying to solve these equations by using implicit method in time. My question is: do we need to derive pressure Poisson equation to solve it? If not, how can I ensure that the continuity equation is satisfied?

Thank you in advance.

Best,
Ann

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, great have you participating. Sadly your question seems to be lacking a [mcve], it also seems to be off-topic, as (I think) you're talking about mathematics and not programming. Instead check out the [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and take their [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see if your question would be on-topic for them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry for my mistake. Please mark this topic as closed.